# how to call php pdo connection class in another page

Tags: php, pdo

I created a connection in `db.php` class like this:

```
class db
    {   
        public $isConnected;
        protected $database;

        public function __construct($username, $password, $host, $dbname, $options=array())
        {
            $this->isConnected = true;
            try { 
                $this->database= new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); 
                $this->database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
                $this->database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            } 
            catch(PDOException $e) { 
                $this->isConnected = false;
                throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
            }
        }       

public function select($query, $params=array()){
            try{ 
                $stmt = $this->database->prepare($query); 
                $stmt->execute($params);
                return $stmt->fetch();  
                }catch(PDOException $e){
                throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
```

and I am accessing this class in `state.php` page like this:

```
<?php
$database = new db("root", "", "localhost", "bhaskar_hindi_dbs", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));  
                $getrows = $database->select("SELECT state_id, state_name FROM state");         
                foreach($getrows as $row){                  
                ?>
```

but I have multiple pages in my project. Now I need to set this below variable also in db class and make a connection to the constructor according to this.

```
$host = localhost;

$username = "";

$password ="";

$dbname = "";

$options = "";
```

Can anyone suggest how to set this variable in the DB class and how to call DB class from state.php page?

Comment: You can include it in a file and call it with `include('connection.php');` example in which file you want.

Comment: ok but how to set connection parameters in db .php file for ex - i need to set connection parameters in class db $host = localhost;

$username = "";

$password ="";

$dbname = "";

$options = ""; this are the parameters

Comment: why do you need to set connection parameters in your class ?

Comment: yes i need to set connection paramaeters also in my DB class

Answer (score 0):

add this at the top of your state.php file

```
require 'db.php';
```

this if the db.php file in the same directory, if not then

```
require 'path_to_where_the_db.php_file_is/db.php';
```

Comment: ok but how to set connection parameters in db .php file for ex - i need to set connection parameters in class   db                      $host = localhost; $username = ""; $password =""; $dbname = ""; $options = ""; this are the parameters . i dont need to pass this paramaeters in state.php file

Answer (score 0):

I dont see the issue if you pass them on in the state.php but if you dont want to you can do this:

```
class db
    {   
        public $isConnected;
        protected $database;
        private $_dbOptionArray;
        const DB_USER = 'root';
        const DB_PASS = 'pass';
        const DB_HOST = 'host';
        const DB_NAME = 'name';




        public function __construct($username, $password, $host, $dbname, $options=array())
        {
         $this->_dbOptionArray = [];//set your options here
            $this->isConnected = true;
            try { 
                $this->database= new PDO("mysql:host={self::DB_HOST};dbname={self::DB_NAME};charset=utf8", self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASS, $this->_dbOptionArray); 
                $this->database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
                $this->database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            } 
            catch(PDOException $e) { 
                $this->isConnected = false;
                throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
            }
        }       

public function select($query, $params=array()){
            try{ 
                $stmt = $this->database->prepare($query); 
                $stmt->execute($params);
                return $stmt->fetch();  
                }catch(PDOException $e){
                throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: $this->_dbOptionArray = []; this line shows error ,   syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\wamp\www\pdo\db.php on line 14

Comment: it means you're using php5.3 or lower, try to set it to array();

Comment: $this->_dbOptionArray = ();   syntax error, unexpected ')' in C:\wamp\www\pdo\includes\db.php on line 14

Comment: its should look like this $this->_dbOptionArray = array(); but if you're not going to use it just remove it all together, also remove it from your pdo instantiation change this ($this->database= new PDO("mysql:host={self::DB_HOST};dbname={self::DB_NAME};charset=utf8", self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASS, $this->_dbOptionArray); ) to this ($this->database= new PDO("mysql:host={self::DB_HOST};dbname={self::DB_NAME};charset=utf8", self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASS);

Answer (score 0):

Set parameters by creating a factory.

**DatabaseFactory.php**

```
include("db.php");

class DatabaseFactory
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new db("root", "", "localhost", "bhaskar_hindi_dbs", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
    }

    public function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->db;
    }
}
```

Then you can include `DatabaseFactory.php` in other pages without having to re-enter the parameters every time. Then use it like this:

```
include "DatabaseFactory.php";
$DBFactory = new DatabaseFactory();
$Database = $DBFactory->getConnection();
$query = ...; // your query
$Database->select($query);
```

You can easily change the parameters, reuse on all your pages or change database type this way later down the road if you wished.

Comment: So I putted everything like you said and tried to call it like this. but when i include this code in my state.php page it shows error in   include "includes/DatabaseFactory.php" 
 $DBFactory = new DatabaseFactory();
 $Database = $DBFactory->getConnection(); Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in

Comment: @rajeshingle I missed a semicolon inside the `__construct()` function. I fixed it if you want to paste it again.

Comment: What line does it say the problem is in? You should find the problem on the previous line number of the error it shows you.

Comment: I didn't test the code, it was just an example. I missed the a semicolon again in `include "DatabaseFactory.php"` by the way. I fixed it now in the example. If that's not the problem show us the code that the error is saying

Comment: state.php page   include "includes/DatabaseFactory.php";
 $DBFactory = new DatabaseFactory();
 $Database = $DBFactory->getConnection(); error syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\wamp\www\pdo\includes\DatabaseFactory.php on line 9

Comment: @rajeshingle I was missing a parenthesis. That should do it. I fixed it in the code now.

Answer (score -1):

You can use another function to extend parent function.

```
class dbConfig extends db {

    private $engine;
    private $host;
    private $database;
    private $user;
    private $pass;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->engine = 'mysql';
        $this->host = 'localhost';
        $this->database = '';
        $this->user = '';
        $this->pass = '';
        $dns = $this->engine.':dbname='.$this->database.";host=".$this->host;
        parent::__construct( $dns, $this->user, $this->pass );
    }
}
```

Comment: A database configuration is not a "type" of database. Extending it just to have access to the internal variables doesn't make sense. The responsibility should be in another class to instantiate his db class.

Comment: i do like above but this give me error on state.php file  in this line   $getrows = $database->select("SELECT state_id, state_name FROM state"); Undefined variable: database